# For a sequence of random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ that satisfies the following conditions:

Tags: probability-theory

For a sequence of random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ that satisfies the following conditions:

1. $X_{n}$ converges in probability to a positive number, i.e., $\exists\ a>0,$ such that $\forall\ \delta>0,$ there is $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-a|>\delta)\rightarrow 0$.
2. For each $X_{n}$, we have an almost sure lower bound, i.e., $X_n>b>-\infty\ \ a.s.$.

Can we then conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}X_n=+\infty\ \ a.s.$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have roughly thought about it intuitively, and I feel that it is correct because as we move along any trajectory, the negative points on this trajectory will definitely become sparser. Furthermore, since the absolute values of these negative points are limited, they will not cancel out the positive points in the end. Therefore, the sequence will eventually diverge to infinity.

Comment: Do you assume that the $X_n$ are independent or are you interested in the general case?

Comment: What I care about is the general case. It can even be regarded as a purely real analyse problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes for the limsup**

In the positive direction one can show that (almost surely)
$$\limsup \sum_{n=1}^N X_n = +\infty,$$
and in fact more strongly
$$\limsup \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N X_n \ge a.$$
*Proof:* Let $Y_n = (a - X_n)^+$. Then $0 \le Y_n \le a + |b|$ almost surely and $E[Y_n] \to 0$. Let $A_N = \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N Y_n$. By Fatou's lemma,
$$E[\liminf A_N] \le \liminf E[A_N] = \liminf \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N E[Y_n] = 0.$$
Since $A_N \ge 0$, it follows that $\liminf A_N = 0$ almost surely. Since $X_n \ge a - Y_n$, it follows that
$$\limsup \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N X_n \ge a - \liminf A_N = a.\qquad\square$$

**No for the liminf**

The answer to your question as written is no. Here is a counterexample. This is a variant of a kind of counterexample sometimes called a "travelling bump".

Let $U \sim U[0,1]$ and define $X_n = -1$ if
$$U \in \log\log n + [-2/\log (n/3), 0] \pmod 1,$$
and otherwise $X_n = +1$. Then
$$\mathbb P(X_n = 1) = 1 - 2 / \log (n/3) \to 1,$$
so $X_n$ converges to $1$ in probability. Now consider any realization. Let $N_0$ be any positive integer, let $z = \lceil \log\log N_0 \rceil$, and let $N \ge N_0$ be the largest integer such that $\log \log N \le z + U$. Then, using the inequality $\log(1+x) \le x$,
$$\log\log(3N) = \log\log(N) + \log (1 + \log 3/\log N) \le \log\log (N) + \log 3/\log N < z + U + 2 / \log N.$$
Since $\log\log(n)$ is an increasing function, it follows that for $N < n \le 3N$ we have
$$z + U < \log\log n < z + U + 2 /\log (n/3),$$
which implies that $X_n = -1$. Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{3N} X_n \le N - 2N = -N \le -N_0.$$
It follows that $\liminf \sum_{n=1}^N X_n = -\infty$.